# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'doogmas3.timelineables' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Vaya por delante que quizás lo he planteado mal, llevo poco tiempo en esto.
Estoy creando una pequeña red social, donde los usuarios pueden dar like a los posts, crear comentarios, etc.
Cada una de las funcionalidades se genera correctamente a traves de sus modelos y controladores.

Pero me gustaria poder tener una especie de timeline para poder mostrar de forma cronologica la actividad de cada usuario, por ejemplo: si ha dado like, si ha comentado en xx post, etc.

Para este proposito he creado una tabla polimorfica donde guardo el id y el modelo de la acitividad y cada vez que un usuario hace una funcion, a parte de guardarla en su tabla correspondiente guardo también el registro en la tabla polimorfica.

**Esta es la migración:**

```
Schema::create('timelines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('timelineable_id');
            $table->string('timelineable_type');
            $table->enum('type', [Timeline::COMMENT, Timeline::SHAREPOST, Timeline::SHARESOCIAL, Timeline::CREATESOCIAL]);
            $table->text('text')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Ahora lo que necesito es poder crear las relaciones necesarias en el modelo timelines para sacar el registro de cada actividad con su correspondiente tabla, por ejemplo para poder hacer algo asi:

```
$timelines->comment  
$timelines->sharepost 
$timelines->sharesocial
```

El modelo timelines lo tengo asi:

```
class Timeline extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    const SURVEY = 1;
    const COMMENT = 2;
    const SHAREPOST = 3;
    const SHARESOCIAL = 4;
    const CREATESOCIAL = 5;


    public function timelineable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Comment::class, 'timelineable');
    }
}
```

Cuando intento acceder a la relacion:

```
{{$timeline->comments}}
```

Me da este error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'doogmas3.timelineables' doesn't exist (SQL: select `comments`.*, `timelineables`.`timeline_id` as `pivot_timeline_id`, `timelineables`.`timelineable_id` as `pivot_timelineable_id`, `timelineables`.`timelineable_type` as `pivot_timelineable_type` from `comments` inner join `timelineables` on `comments`.`id` = `timelineables`.`timelineable_id` where `timelineables`.`timeline_id` = 45 and `timelineables`.`timelineable_type` = App\Models\Comment) (View: C:\laragon\www\doogmas\resources\views\livewire\front-end\social\share-content.blade.php)
```

El controlador trae todo el timeline asi:

```
$timelines = Timeline::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->whereIn('user_id', $followings)->get();
```

Esto me devuelve el registro de actividad de todos los usuarios que sigo.
y mi idea es hacer un foeach e ir mostrando todas las actividades que estan registradas.

Por ejemplo:

- El usuario x ha comentado en yy posts
- el usuario y ha dado like a este post
- el usuario z ha creado este post

Evaluo en cada iteración y depende el type de la table timeline pues muestro una relacion u otra

```
@if($timeline->type==Comments) {
   $timeline->comments
}
```

y así con todo los type

Comment: Si, estoy probando cosas pero no consigo que funcione

Comment: He añadido mas detalles

Comment: la tabla como se llama? porque ahi esta tu problema...

Comment: al principio le pusiste nombre timelines, y luego la usaste como timelineable, si no entiendo mal el codigo...

Comment: Aqui es donde estoy confundido, ya que segun he entendido en los ejemplos del manual habia que llamar asi a la relación. La tabla se llama timeline

Comment: Bueno el error es claro, esta buscando la tabla equivocada... de donde proviene, no se, porque no veo en ningun lado que tengas escrito timelineables

Comment: pero es que aunque cambie la relacion de timelineable a timeline también me da error

Comment: @betaM esta puesto en el modelo Timeline. Te refieres a la relacion comments()?

Comment: Agregado ......

Answer (score 0):

Si `timeline` es tu tabla polimórfica, entonces en el modelo `Timeline` tienes el primer error al declarar ahi mismo el método `comments` el cual de hecho deberás mover a la clase del modelo que va a estar vinculado con el anterior mencionado.

Entonces tu clase `Timeline` deberías tener algo como lo siguiente:

```
class Timeline extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    const SURVEY = 1;
    const COMMENT = 2;
    const SHAREPOST = 3;
    const SHARESOCIAL = 4;
    const CREATESOCIAL = 5;


    public function timelineable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Ahora es en el otro modelo donde debes indicar la relación por medio del método `comments`
pero aqui esta el segundo error, estas pasando como primer argumento una clase llamada `Comment` cuando de hecho la que deberías indicar es: `TimeLine` pues es esta la polimórfica, de la siguiente manera:

```
class OtroModelo extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Timeline::class, 'timelineable');
    }
}
```

Ahora si podrás escribir la consulta de este modo:

```
OtroModelo::with('comments')->get();
```

De hecho si me permites la observación, si la clase se llama `TimeLine` entonces el método no debería ser `comments` si no entodo caso `timelines` digo para tratar de llevar orden en el código que escribimos y lo que se supone que esta destinado a hacer.

Sugiero [revises de nuevo la doc. al respecto](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

Comment: Es lo que me estaba temiendo, que mi idea tal y como la estaba planteando no se podía hacer. De la manera que planteas no me sirve ya que la tabla timeline solo esta creada para poder traer la actividad de los usuarios (Likes, dislikes, comments, etc ) de forma cronologica, No tiene otro sentido. Tendré que buscar otra forma de hacerlo. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Si es así, entonces me parece que no es una relación polimórfica lo que buscas @Alberto suerte revisando de nuevo tus requerimientos